# Automatically import bookmarks from Chrome to Internet Explorer once a week

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, bookmarks

Is there any way to set up a batch file or something to import bookmarks from Chrome to Internet Explorer once every so often, removing all bookmarks from IE? I've tried using Xmarks to sync between the two, but I always end up with duplicates, empty folders, etc. What I want is one way sync, overwriting all bookmarks in IE.